# How to get raw contents of attachment using Graph API?

Tags: php, character-encoding, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to get the contents of a file, but something is off about the encoding with the content bytes being returned. When I view the file in Notepad++, the contents look something like this:

```
UÏMÌØˆ€aX!D"AŠMtPïq¡ª†f24O]J¦¢’k¿ÇFcX+|¿¯÷q”z{CîËC~ãZVŸâÆù ´*ëáµå:ã/•þ57Yü*—kØ&Ž=NDüßÒLó>@÷.MÊ
×núšÙÄlsb´Ò·SFAÙá~˜ wpÌ&—wY¯ÇpÊúé(¯uïû°×Œ†ˆ÷.”ÒB1ŒKŽ|G;m««¼Õ‘h’IRLp°,µ‰<ÿ¥*‡ë>Ž´ÌÇRtA‰öjJäÂY<5&u„óNæÓÓ¿Md¡U§ÎkäÐÁJÛO{9’^¬C]Ó<ô;Ë:N“šK8KÏH1
```

I call the Graph endpoint to get the contents of the file like this:

```
public function getRawAttachmentContents($emailAddress, $messageId)
{
    return $this->graph->createRequest("GET", "/users/$emailAddress/messages/$messageId/attachments/{attachmentId}")
        ->setReturnType(get_class(new \Microsoft\Graph\Model\FileAttachment()))
        ->execute();
}
```

This is what gets returned when I make the call. The contents look very different. It's like they're in a different format. How can I get them to be in the same format as the original? When I call the Graph API to get the raw contents (using the $value at the end) nothing gets returned. [image]

**Edit:** So I figured out how to get the contents of the attachment as they appear when I open the file in Notepad++. I do this:

```php
public function getRawAttachmentContents($emailAddress, $messageId, $attachmentId)
    {
        $attachment = $this->graph->createRequest("GET", "/users/$emailAddress/messages/$messageId/attachments/$attachmentId/\$value")
            ->execute();
        $attachment->getRawBody()->rewind();
        $file_contents = $attachment->getRawBody()->getContents();
        return $file_contents;
}
```

However, when I try uploading the contents returned from that function, an attachment doesn't even get created in the draft message (before, when I uploaded the plain text, it was at least creating an attachment to the draft message, and I was getting a 201 created response on the final upload of the bytes, but the attachment was corrupt).

Comment: Can you please in [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) whether you are getting the same result, try using this example: [Get the MIME raw contents of a meeting invitation item attachment on a message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-9-get-the-mime-raw-contents-of-a-meeting-invitation-item-attachment-on-a-message)

Comment: If I use Graph Explorer, then the response says "This response contains content that may not be viewable on this editor.Click to download file." When I download the file, it is just the audio file, and it works fine.